# configure web.config to allow js from remote sources

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, web-config

I have a `login.aspx`, which have a `asp:Login`, now in this page i want to allow some scripts, which are injected in the master of my application. But this scripts are not in local path, but in another server, i know if this scripts are local i could configure like this, to allowed in the login.aspx page

```
<location path="scripts">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow users="*"/>
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

That assume that the scripts are in the local folder styles, how can i modifed or change this configure to allow the scripts that are in this route

```
<script src="http://Example/scripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
```

I tried like this but it doesn't work

```
<location path="http://Example/scripts/">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow users="*"/>
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

Comment: What do the scripts have to do with authentication? I don't see how an external script (stylesheet?) ties in with authentication...

Comment: I don't know that yet, but if I comment
`<authorization>
    <allow users="*"/>
  </authorization>` it works perfectly, so I assume it has to be related to the authorization...

Comment: I think I understand the issue now. If you allow access to that folder in the application on the other server, it works?

Comment: `<location>` path attribute must be a relative virtual path, I can't set a path like `"http://Example/scripts/"`

Answer (score 0):

If it causes the trouble then this is **the other server** which does so.

It means that you have to create the authorization exception on the server hosting the css file, not the one which has the *.aspx referencing it.